# Bootstrapping with replacement

Tags: bootstrap

If I want to nonparametrically bootstrap the following matrix (with replacement):

```
1   2   15  12  14  22
3   5   1   9   29  19
2   22  12  11  9   13
14  3   6   16  17  23 
5   34  22  12  13  16
7   14  13  19  17  3
```

Would I "jumble" up only the rows, to obtain matrices like:

```
5   34  22  12  13  16
14  3   6   16  17  23 
2   22  12  11  9   13
3   5   1   9   29  19
2   22  12  11  9   13
5   34  22  12  13  16
```

Or would I jumble up every element to obtain rows with any combination of all the values in the original matrix?

The columns represent different species of animal and the rows different areas of woodland, the elements are the number of animals observed in each area. I'm looking to form confidence intervals for the diversity index of the whole woodland.

I'm defining the diversity index (Shannon index) by summing the rows to get a species count for the whole woodland, then performing a diversity index on these rows. It returns a single value.

Comment: It depends on what the matrix means and why you are bootstrapping.  Please inform us!

Comment: Is there some structure within the rows you are interested in exploring? Could you explain the problem a bit more? Also, I am pretty sure the bootstrap is sampling with replacement and that nonparamentric bootstrap is redundant, because bootstrapping is a nonparametric technique, though I might just be failing to understand your question.

Comment: The columns represent different species of animal and the rows different areas of woodland, the elements are the number of animals observed in each area. I'm looking to form confidence intervals for the diversity index of the whole woodland.

Comment: Apologies, in my question I said "without replacement", I actually meant "with replacement".

Comment: Alright that makes more sense. How are you defining the diversity index of the whole woodland? Is it some linear combination of the animals in a given area or something else? You have to define a statistic to bootstrap a confidence interval.

Comment: I'm defining the diversity index [(Shannon index)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Shannon_index) by summing the rows to get a species count for the whole woodland, then performing a diversity index on these rows. It returns a single value. Sorry I didn't provide all this information in the question, I had no idea it was important!

Comment: asjohnson, bootstrapping can be either parametric or nonparametric: it is not inherently nonparametric.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Parametric_bootstrap.

Comment: dplanet, please edit your question to reflect this additional information (so that readers don't have to wade through all these comments).  If you can, you should also add information about how you obtained the data: the treatment of a full census would differ from that of samples (and the treatment for samples would depend on how they were obtained, such as by quadrat counts, transects, or whatever).

Comment: Did you mean to say you sum the colums to get the total count of the species (as per your first comment the columns represent the different animal species)? One other point of clarification, are you getting 1 shannon index per woodland region (row) and then averaging the shannon indexes to get 1 value or are you getting 1 shannon value per woodland region (in this case 6)? Sorry, new to the Shannon Index and wikipedia made it look like the shannon index would give 6 values for the data you have there.

Comment: Thanks whuber, you are right. I always think of it in the context of a non-parametric class, but now that you mention it I do recall the parametric bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some structure you are interested in preserving that relates to woodland region I would resample within each row, so for the first row you would sample with replacement from

```
 1   2   15  12  14  22
```

for the second row it would be 6 draws with replacement from

```
 3   5   1   9   29  19
```

and repeat that for all rows.

Then based on that information aggregate your rows and calculate your shannon index. You mentioned wanting confidence intervals, so you could do the percentage method, which would consist of repeating this process 10000+ (some very large number) of times and then cutting off 2.5% from the tails of the values to give you the end points of a bootstrapped 95% CI. I think I find this method the most compelling, since it seems like you would measure in different woodland regions for a reason.

By extension I suppose you could also do the process by column reselection if there was some relationship with in each species you were interested in maintaining.

If there is no structure you are interested in as far as woodland regions or species go, you could just pool all of the numbers together and sample with replacement from that pool for each element in the maitrix (which I believe you suggest in your post). Then create your shannon index and confidence interval.

Comment: In the absence of a clear probability model--which is not in evidence at this time because the nature of the data collection method has not (yet) been disclosed--it is not possible to tell whether this advice will produce good or bad results.